# Changing the width of BarLegend with Contour argument

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, legending

**Bug introduced in 10.0.2 or ealier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

Is it possible to change the aspect ratio of the `BarLegend` in Mathematica?

The option `LegendMarkerSize`, in my case below, only changes the overall length of the bar.

So, for the example image below, how can I make the colour bar wider? Note that because of the contours argument, using `LegendMarkerSize -> {300, 300}` has no effect.

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0.0, 1.0}}, 20, LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
 LegendLabel -> Style["Intensity", Bold, FontSize -> 14], 
 LabelingFunction -> (Style[NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 1}], 
     FontSize -> 12] &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of `BarLegend` is hard-coded to `15` printer points in the functions `` Legending`LegendDump`iColorGradientLegend `` and `` Legending`LegendDump`iColorBandLegend ``. We can post-process the `BarLegend` output to change this number:

```
ClearAll[makeWide]
makeWide[w_: 30] := RawBoxes[ToBoxes[#] /. {15/2 | 7.5 -> w/2, 
   -15/2 | (-7.5) -> -w/2}] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
bl = BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0.0, 1.0}}, 30, LegendMarkerSize -> 400, 
   LegendLabel -> Style["Intensity", Bold, FontSize -> 14], 
   "LabelingFunction" -> (Style[NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 1}], FontSize -> 15] &)] ;

Row[{bl, makeWide[] @ bl, makeWide[60] @ bl, makeWide[100] @ bl, makeWide[400] @bl },
 Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If you look under the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendMarkerSize.html) for `LegendMarkerSize`, you will see it accepts values of the form: `{w, h}`. So, you can specify the width, for example

```
BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendMarkerSize -> {100, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work with the OP's case: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uWMqG.png. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @Öskå its the contours (2nd argument) that is doing it. Reporting it.

Comment: I figured it was the second argument indeed, thanks for reporting it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, meant to clarify but got called away -  I did try these options but couldn't get it to work. Thanks!