# How to make barlegend the same height/width as the plot

Tags: plotting

Is there a way to make the barlegend in a density or contour plot the same width/ height as the plot, depending on if you position the barlegend above or after the plot? The only related post that I found was this one [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/make-legend-same-height-as-plot#), and it is over 5 years old.

Comment: closely related q/a: [Changing the width of BarLegend with Contour argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64846/125)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {100, 300}]]
```

[image]

```
 DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
     ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
     PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {300, 300}]]
```

[image]

**Edit:**

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {300, 100}], Above]]
```

[image]

Comment: Btw, do you know if it is possible to change the appearance of the legend, as you did, and have it placed above the plot?